# Breaking the Caesar Cipher with brute force

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

The first two functions are mine:

```
def rotated(n: int):
    '''Returns a rotated letter if parameter is greater than 26'''
    ALPHABET = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    if n >= 26:
        n %= 26
    return ALPHABET[n:26] + ALPHABET[:n]
assert rotated(0) == 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
assert rotated(26) == 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

def Caesar_decrypt(text: str, key: int) -> str:
    '''Returns a decryption of parameter text and key''' 
    text = text.lower()
    key_to_zero = str.maketrans(rotated(key),rotated(0))
    return text.translate(key_to_zero)
```

But my partner worked on the 3rd function:

> ```
> def Caesar_break(code: str)-> str:
>     'Decrypts the coded text without a key'
>     file = open('wordlist.txt', 'r')
>     dic = []
>     dlist = file.readlines()
>     wl = []
>     l = []
>     cl = []
>     swl = []
>     sw = ''
>     for words in code:
>         if words.isalnum() or words.isspace():
>             l.append(words)
>         else:
>             l.append(' ')
>     Ncode = ''.join(l)
>     codelist = Ncode.split()
>
>     high = 0
>     for i in range(1,27):
>         highesthit = 0
>         hit = 0
>         out = Caesar_decrypt(Ncode, i)
>         e = 0
>         l = 0
>         while l < len(dlist):
>             dic.append(dlist[l].split()[0])
>             l += 1
>         while e < len(dic):
>             if out == dic[e]: 
>                 hit += 1
>                 e += 1
>         if hit > highesthit:
>                 high = i
>                 highesthit = hit
>     return(Caesar_decrypt(Ncode, high))
> ```

I can't contact him right now, so I was wondering if there is a simpler way to break the Caesar code using brute force. My partner used too many random letters in his code, so I can't really understand it.

Note: "wordlist.txt" is a document we downloaded down with all of the words in the dictionary. [Here](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~kay/wordlist.txt) is the link for reference.

The `Caesar_break` code is supposed to work like this:

```
Caesar_break('amknsrcp qagclac') == 'computer science'
```

Comment: Your partner tests *every* code from 1 to 127 while you only test a..z. Check your course notes to see if that is overkill. For the rest it seems he counts the number of recognizable words after each decode, and returns the value which resulted in the highest number. Seems as straightforward as a Brute Force approach can be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code breaking! Yay! The simplest way to break the caeser cipher is to assume that your encoded text is representative of the actual language it's in with respect to the frequency of letters. In English, that relative frequency looks kind of like:

```
"etaoinshrdlcumwfgypbvkjxqz"
# most to least common characters in English according to
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency
```

The fastest way to break a Caeser Cipher, then, is to create a `collections.Counter` of the letters in your encrypted phrase, find the most common couple, and assume each one (in turn) is `e`. Calculate your difference from there, and apply the decrypt cipher. Test to see if it's valid English, and ta-da!

```
import collections

def difference(a: str, b: str) -> int:
    a, b = a.lower(), b.lower()
    return ord(b) - ord(a)

def english_test(wordlist: "sequence of valid english words",
                 text: str) -> bool:
    """english_test checks that every word in `text` is in `wordlist`"""
    return all(word in wordlist for word in text)

def bruteforce_caeser(text: str) -> str:
    with open('path/to/wordlist.txt') as words:
        wordlist = {word.strip() for word in words}
        # set comprehension!
    c = collections.Counter(filter(lambda ch: not ch.isspace(), text))
    most_common = c.most_common()  # ordered by most -> least common
    for ch, _ in most_common:
        diff = difference('e', ch)
        plaintext = Caeser_decrypt(text, diff)
        if english_test(wordlist, plaintext):
            return plaintext
```

There's a subtle logic error in this code though, w.r.t. an assumption made about the input text. I'll leave it as an exercise to the student to find the logic error and think of what small change could be made to ensure a result on any input. As a hint: try rotating and then decrypting the following phrase:

> Judy I don't think it's right for you to contact such a marksman as this man, for without warning this marksman could shoot and kill you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that a ciphertext was encrypted with ceaser (x+3)mod25 you can just float letters. I would make all text lowercase first. then get asci values all chracters. For example asci(a)=97, make it 97-97=0; for b make it 98-97=1.Then I would make 2 arrays 1 for characters, 1 for integer values of chracters....